# UI5 remove duplicate feed list items

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

I have a Feed List for posting comments in my UI5 xml view

```
<layout:content>
    <m:FeedInput post="onFeedPost" class="sapUiSmallMarginTopBottom"/>
    <m:List id="feedList" showSeparators="Inner" items="{path: '/table', sorter: {path: 'DATE', descending: true}}">
        <m:FeedListItem sender="{MEMBERID}" timestamp="{DATE}" text="{COMMENT}" convertLinksToAnchorTags="All"/>
    </m:List>
</layout:content>
```

I want to not display duplicate comments that have the same text and date, but keep them in the database. My idea was to in the controller iterate over over the items to do this, but I am not sure what to do with the resulting array

```
var results = [];
var comments = feed.getItems();

for (var n = 0; n < comments.length - 1; n++) {
    var contained = false; 

    for (var m = n + 1; m < comments.length; m++) {
        if (comments[n].getText() === comments[m].getText() && 
            comments[n].getDate() === comments[m].getDate()) {
            comments.pop(m);

            contained = true;

            if (!results.includes(comments[n])) {
                results.push(comments[n]);
            }
        }
    }

    if (!contained && !results.includes(comments[n])) {
        results.push(comments[n]);
    }
}

// replace list items with results array
```

I can't figure out how to replace the feed list's items with the new array as there is a getItems function but not a setItems function. It occurs to me there is probably a simpler more idiomatic UI5 way to do this but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: Do the above operation on model data. Do, `comments = model.getProperty('/table');` then apply filter logic and finally store back the result in array : `model.setProperty('/table', results)`. Here, I'm assuming model is JSON Model.

Comment: @RahulBhardwaj 'comments = model.getProperty('/table');' for my table returns undefined even though it shows up in the bindings. I use an odata service for the backend but create json to do requests (create, remove). Not  sure if this makes it a json model or not.

Answer (score 2):

First off, the correct way to handle this situation is in the OData service. The service should remove the duplicates before sending the data to the client. If we assume, however, that you can't do this server side, then you have some options.

1.) Do not bind the list items to anything. Instead, use the ODataModel to read the data, then filter out duplicates, create a new list item and add it to the list

Read the data using the ODataModel, then pass the results to a method that will filter and add them items to the list

```
oModel.read("/EntitySet", {
    success: function(oResponse) {
        this._addCommentsToList(oResponse.results)
    }.bind(this)
})
```

In your method to handle the results, you'll need to do three things -- create a new FeedListItem, set the binding context of the list item, and then add the list item to the list

```
var aDistinctComments = //use your logic to filter out duplicates
aDistinctComments.forEach(function(oComment) {
    //to set the binding context, you'll need the entity key/path
    var sCommentKey = oModel.createKey("/EntitySet", oComment)
    //create a new binding context
    var oContext = oModel.createBindingContext(sCommentKey)
    //create a new FeedListItem
    var oItem = new FeedListItem({
        sender: "{MemberId}",
        ...
    });
    //set the context of the item and add it to the list
    oItem.setBindingContext(oContext);
    oList.addItem(oItem);
})
```

2.) Bind the list directly to the OData entity set and then when the list receives the data, iterate over the items and hide the duplicates

```
<List items="{/EntitySet}" updateFinished="onListUpdateFinished"....>

----- onListUpdateFinished ---
var aItems = oList.getItems();
for (var m = n + 1; m < aItems.length; m++) {
    //set a boolean, true if duplicate
    var bDuplicate = aItems[m].getText() ==== aItems[n].getText() &&
                     aItems[m].getDate() === aItems[n].getDate();
    //set the visibility of the item to true if it is not a duplicate
    aItems[m].setVisible(!bDuplicate)
}
```

3.) Read the data manually, remove duplicates, and stash it in a JSON model, and bind the table to your JSON model path

```
oModel.read("/EntitySet", {
    success: function(oResponse) {
        this._addCommentsToJSONModel(oResponse.results)
    }.bind(this)
})
```

You can stash an array of objects in your JSON model, and then bind the table items to that path

```
 var aDistinctComments = // your logic to get distinct comments
 oJSONModel.setProperty("/comments", aDistinctComments)
 oList.setModel(oJSONModel);

 -----

 <List items="{/comments"}....>
```

4.) Bind your list items to your entity set, iterate over the items, and then remove duplicates from the list. I don't recommend this approach. Removing items manually from lists bound to an entity set can lead to trouble with duplicate IDs.

```
 var oItem = //use your logic to find a duplicate list item
 oList.removeItem(oItem)
```

I recommend first handling this server side in the OData service, and if that's not an option, then use option 1 above. This will give you the desired results and maintain the binding context of your list items. Options 2 and 3 will get you the desired results, but depending on your applicaiton, may make working with the list more difficult.

Answer (score -1):

Here is one approach :

Do not directly bind the list to your oData. 
You can create a JSON model which will be the resulting model after removing duplicate items.

Bind the JSON model to the List as such:

`var oList = this.getView().byId("feedList");
oList.bindAggregation("items", "pathToJsonArray", template);`

(The template is feedlistitem in this case).

Comment: How do I get the feed list item template and what it the pathToJsonArray supposed to be?

Comment: Can you clarify how pathToJsonArray is supposed to point to the array I have?

Comment: this has to be the path of the array.
As per the example code(XML) above, 
I can say the exact syntax should be:

oList.bindAggregation("items", "/table", new sap.ui.core.FeedListItem({text:"{COMMENT}"}) );

Provided "COMMENT" is a property of the table array.

Comment: I don't understand. It seems there are steps missing in between you haven't added. I have an array from list.getItems(). "/table" will not point to that array as far as I'm aware. Please fill in the missing parts.